# How do I access EntityManager from within Grails service (JPA + GAE)

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, jpa, grails-plugin

I'm having trouble accessing the EntityManager from within a grails service:

**My setup is as follows...**

- Basic Grails application with the AppEngine and GORM-JPA plugins
- Default settings for pretty much everything. I haven't touched resources.groovy, persistence.xml etc.

**Some things are good...**

- I am able to access the EntityManager from within controllers by simply adding "def entityManager".

**But...**

- I have a service that I'm trying to access the EntityManager from, however, I get a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is already closed!" exception.
- Is a plugin closing the EntityManager somewhere? Do I need to change the scope of the EntityManager somehow? Is there some XML file I need to update to ensure proper injection?

  ```
  class GoogleCalendarService implements InitializingBean {
      void afterPropertiesSet() {
      }


     def entityManager


     public OAuthToken getAccessToken(User u) {
         //can't access entityManager from here
         entityManager.newQuery(...) //throws an IllegalStateException
     }


  }
  ```

One weird note:
For some reason, if I re-save the service while Jetty is up and running the service is able to access the EntityManager just once. If I click reload (and have the controller access the service again) the service can no longer access the EntityManager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the right way to do this is use the EntityManagerFactory, like this:

```
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils

class GoogleCalendarService implements InitializingBean {
    void afterPropertiesSet() {

    }

    def entityManagerFactory
    EntityManager em

    public OAuthToken getAccessToken(User u) {
        em = EntityManagerFactoryUtils.getTransactionalEntityManager(entityManagerFactory)
        //do stuff with em
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but entityManagerFactory is null. Any ideas? Thanks